# CSS Background color works in DW but not in browser

Tags: html, css, background

page in question - www.pointbank.com/testerfile/

I created a div id - *div id="PBredbackground600"* in the default.css file to allow me to change the background color of the entire Content - *div id="content"* - section's  background  for one specific page on the website.  I have used both img and colors (six hex), and can get both to appear perfectly within DreamWeaver. However neither will work in Chrome or IE. What am I not getting??

entire html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/default.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>PointBank Loans | Denton County Community Bank, Texas</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<meta name="description" content="PointBank has the right financing for personal or business loans at competitive terms." />
<meta name="keywords" content="pointbank loans, pointbank personal loan, pointbank business loan, denton county loan, personal loans denton tx., business loan texas" />


<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->

<link href="/includes/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link href="/includes/css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="/includes/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/includes/js/ddbelatedpng.js"></script>
<script>DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, div, p, a, input');</script>
<![endif]-->
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
<script src="/includes/js/default.js"></script>

<!-- InstanceParam name="showBreadcrumb" type="boolean" value="true" -->

<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/analytics.php'); ?>
</head>

<body <?php if( $is_homepage ) { echo 'class="homepage"'; } ?>>

<div id="header">
    <a href="/" title="PointBank"><img src="/images/pointbank.png" width="220" height="92" alt="PointBank - Proudly Serving Denton County, Texas" /></a>
    <p id="top"><a href="/" title="PointBank">Home</a> | <a href="/contact-us/" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a> | <a href="/about-us/locations/" title="Locations">Locations</a> | <a href="https://www.pcsbanking.net/onlinebanking1/login.r?t-bank=111906006" title="Online Banking" target="_blank">Online Banking</a></p>
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/menu.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="online-banking">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editHeader" --><img src="/images/headers/loans.png" width="704" height="168" alt="Loans at PointBank" /><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/online-banking.php'); ?>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <?php if( $is_homepage ) { ?>
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/homepage.php'); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="page">
    <p id="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Home</a> &#8250; <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editBreadcrumb" --><span>Loans</span><!-- InstanceEndEditable --></p>
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editContent" -->


    <div id="PBredbackground600">




    <h2>PointBank Loan  Opportunities2</h2>
    <p>     As the leading Denton County community bank, PointBank has a  strong financial foundation that provides us with the lending power we need to  work with you on any size loan. With our local decision-making, you will find  us <strong>flexible and responsive to your personal or business needs</strong>.</p>
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><strong><a href="/personal-banking/loans/"><img src="/images/icons/checking-and-savings.png" alt="Personal Loans" width="48" height="48" />Personal  Loans</a></strong><br />
            Whatever your unique needs, we have the right financing for personal loans at competitive terms.</li>
        <li><strong><a href="/mortgage/"><img src="/images/icons/mortgage.png" alt="Mortgage Lending" width="48" height="48" />Mortgage  Lending</a></strong><br />
            PointBank Mortgage is a full service lender based in Denton County  that specializes in Conventional, USDA-Rural Development, FHA and VA loans.</li>
    </ul>
    <h6>For immediate loan pre-qualification or if you have any preliminary questions before you apply for a loan, call (940) 686-7000.</h6>

    </div>

    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/usa-patriot-act.php'); ?>





    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="editSidebar" -->



    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/sidebar-loans.php'); ?>

    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/sidebar.php'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <br clear="all" />

        <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/branches.php'); ?>




</div>

<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/php/footer.php'); ?>

<?php if( $isBlog ) { ?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

here is the code in default.css

```
#PBredbackground600 {
    background-color:#80FF00;
    font:"Comic Sans MS", cursive
}
```

This set of code shows using the color option instead of an image file, and I also changed the font to aid in identifying if the code was being executed or partially executed.  Neither the color nor the font change show up in browser, but work fine in DW.

Here is the dev tools code. Don't have enough rep for image upload. I dont't see any expansion of the PBredbackground600 div, I think perhaps there is a div-page or div-content setting that is overriding the proper display of the div-PBredbackground600, but cannot find what it is, I have looked thru the default.css at the page and content tags but do not know code well enough to recognize an overriding command or setting.

Copied from style tab from chrome dev tools

```
element.style {
}
*, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, ul li, ol li, blockquote, form, fieldset, legend, object, param, hr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
*, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, ul li, ol li, blockquote, form, fieldset, legend, object, param, hr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Inherited from body
body {
font: normal 14px/22px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #b9cbcd url(/images/overall-background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: Where is the CSS please ?

Comment: We're going to need to see some more code and an explanation on how you're including your `default.css` file. If you want to change the background color of the `#content` DIV why not target with a body class? First add class to the body tag, ie `<body class="about">` then in your CSS file `.about #content { background-color: green; }`.

Comment: Added more code. I only need to change the background color of the content secton on a single page, not every page.

Comment: It appears as though the div PBredbackground600 does not get executed in browser. When i inspect element I can't find any trace of it other than its original html code listing. Could the Page or Content div's be preventing it from appearing?

Comment: Michal had sent a fiddle showing that it does get executed correctly in the browser, thanks Michal for that.  Oddly though his answer and thread has disappeared from this question thread?? It does appear that another style is overriding, how can I track down this offending code?

Comment: is there a chance that all elements within the div are floated?

Comment: Thanks Marcel - this is where my skill level would end- what do you mean floated? where would i see that?

Comment: Ifound this in the default.css. Is this what i am looking for? #content #page {
 float: left;
 width: 600px;
 overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

better to provide css, but this is how you should have it in your css file:

```
div#PBredbackground600 { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

changed based on actual css provided, to force it:

```
#PBredbackground600 {
    background-color:#80FF00 !important;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
```

Comment: Thanks maxi - tried it, same results, works in DW, but not in chrome browser.

Comment: you can use chrome dev tools ( F12 ) to inspect actual styles applied, it could be overridden by other style. Also you can try background-color: yellow !important;

Comment: I did use f12 but cannot see where it is being overridden by another style.

Comment: Tried !important - didn't work. Thoughts on how i can figure out which style is overriding it?

Comment: please post screenshot of chrome dev tools with selected div, interested in styles tab ( at the right )